# How to set Cursor position in SWT Text

Tags: java, text, swt

I am trying to set the cursor position of SWT `Text` to the end after appending string. I am aware of changing cursor position of SWT `StyledText`, but not sure of SWT `Text`. If you people have come across this Challenge and found the solution kindly share it.

Comment: Please use as many tags as possible to describe your question, not just `swt`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have a look at [`Text#setSelection(int)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Text.html#setSelection(int)):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display d = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(d);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);

    text.setText("Some random text here...");

    text.setSelection(text.getText().length());


    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
        while (!d.readAndDispatch())
            d.sleep();
}
```

This will set the cursor to the end.